# Why is Nokogiri failing on multiple pseudo element selectors?

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri, and I ran into a problem with pseudo-selector chaining.

These work:

```
document.at_css(".link:not(.button)")
document.at_css(".link:after")
```

But *this* doesn't:

```
document.at_css(".link:not(.button):after")
```

I get a rather long error message along these lines:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:87:in `on_error':
unexpected ':' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fc9540932b8 @type=:CONDITIONAL_SELECTOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fc954093da8 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["*"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fc954093f38 @type=:COMBINATOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fc95409b350 @type=:CLASS_CONDITION, @value=["link"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fc95409ab80 @type=:NOT, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007fc95409acc0 @type=:CLASS_CONDITION, @value=["button"]>]>]>]>]' 
(Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: This might be a question for the [Nokogiri-talk list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/nokogiri-talk). They were adding jQuery compatibility, but how much and how far they've gotten... dunno. jQuery is a moving target. You might need to do some post filtering in Ruby, or see if XPath can give you access as it has a richer set of modifiers.

Comment: I thought this might have been the case; however all three selectors are valid CSS, even if nokogiri cannot find a pseudo element it is still being styled. It's not just after either, replace that with hover and it will still cause an exception.

Comment: A selector string containing "multiple pseudo element selectors" as given in the title would actually be invalid if the pseudo-elements were attached to the same compound selector. There is only a single pseudo-class (`:not()`) and a single pseudo-element (`:after`) at most in use here, so these are valid selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample HTML it's hard to tell what you're after, but I'll take a wild-shot starting with a replacement of:

```
document.at_css(".link:not(.button):after")
```

with:

```
document.css(".link").reject{ |n| n['class'][/\b button \b/ix] }.first.next_sibling
```

I've read comments that some of the CSS isn't an exact match to jQuery's so workarounds are needed. Take a glance at:

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/907

The `doc.css("input:not([disabled])").count` work around might be useful.

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/ROADMAP.md

Comment: I need nokogiri to find an instance (in html) of a css selector; if it cannot handle all cases then I will probably have to do some Ruby logic in addition.

Comment: After further research I found that this is a known issue (https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/451) and will hopefully be addressed with the 2.0 release of nokogiri. I've accepted your answer as a thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 3):

After isn't really a selector.
You might need to explain what you're trying to do otherwise I suggest:

```
document.at(".link:not(.button)").after "content"
```

Comment: It's a valid *CSS* selector, even if it cannot target anything in the DOM.

Comment: Hmm, I would argue that it's a valid css element but not a selector.

Comment: :after is listed in the CSS Reference on w3schools as a *selector*. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp - If it is not a selector then what is it? CSS rules follow the format selector, selector { property:value; }

Comment: It's ok to disagree. To my way of thinking a selector selects things.

Comment: Maybe we can find some middle ground: `:after` (and [its kin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)) are *pseudo-elements*. Therefore, a selector containing one can be considered a *pseudo-selector*.

Comment: @Mark Thomas: As if we didn't have enough meanings for "pseudo-selector" already...

Comment: @pguardiario: There is no such thing as a "css element", unless you're referring to a pseudo-element.

Comment: @Ben: `:after` is a pseudo-element - it's part of the selector syntax, but it represents something that cannot be expressed via a conventional element selector. A selector can optionally contain at most one pseudo-element (all the details can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax)) and it'll remain a valid selector according to the spec. But for a DOM implementation, such a selector can't be *used* - even if the element in the selector is matched, you're targeting a pseudo-element and not the actual element.

Comment: @Ben: Or to put it more simply - you can only use a pseudo-element in certain situations that accept a selector, such as a CSS rule. We're not dealing with a CSS rule here, but if `.link:after` works while `.link:not(.button):after` doesn't, then something else is wrong as you've found out in the comments on another answer.

Comment: @BoltClock - of course there is. A css element is an element that can be targeted with css. We could argue over semantics I suppose but what's the point?